# Python raw_input doesn't work after using subprocess module

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, plink

I'm using the subprocess module to invoke plink and run some commands on a remote server.  This works as expected, but after a successful call to `subprocess.check_call` or `subprocess.check_output` the `raw_input` method seems to block forever and doesn't accept input at the command line.

I've reduced it to this simple example:

```
import subprocess

def execute(command):
    return subprocess.check_call('plink.exe -ssh ' + USER + '@' + HOST + ' -pw ' + PASSWD + ' ' + command)

input = raw_input('Enter some text: ')
print('You entered: ' + input)

execute('echo "Hello, World"')

# I see the following prompt, but it's not accepting input
input = raw_input('Enter some more text: ')
print('You entered: ' + input)
```

I see the same results with `subprocess.check_call` and `subprocess.check_output`.  If I replace the final `raw_input` call with a direct read from stdin (`sys.stdin.read(10)`) the program does accept input.

This is Python 2.7 on Windows 7 x64.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?'

Edit:  If I change `execute` to call something other than plink it seems to work okay.

```
def execute(command):
    return subprocess.check_call('cmd.exe /C ' + command)
```

This suggests that plink might be the problem.  However, I can run multiple plink commands directly in a console window without issue.

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine around to test this, and can't replicate it here, but have you tried passing `close_fds=True` to the `subprocess.check_call` function?

Comment: Just tried that and got the same result.

Comment: I can't reproduce this on my Windows machine. Does this happen if you run a program other than plink? I wonder if plink is messing with the terminal in some weird way that ends up breaking `raw_input`.

Comment: Good idea.  Tried that and it does seem to work correctly.  Not sure what plink is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by attaching stdin to devnull:

```
def execute(command):
    return subprocess.check_call('plink.exe -ssh ' + USER + '@' + HOST + ' -pw ' + PASSWD + ' ' + command, stdin=open(os.devnull))
```